# Placeholder not working on safari windows in input number

Tags: html, css, safari

i am trying to change placeholder color in input but safari(only windows) is not showing placeholder

html

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Number">
```

CSS

```
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: You can safely forget about Safari Windows 5.1.7: it's [VERY outdated (4.5 yo)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29#Safari_5). It was nice in 2010-11 to be able to test Safari without a Mac but Apple stopped releasing a browser on Windows (and releasing any security fix) and you now need a Mac and an iPhone to test on desktop and mobile Safari. Nobody uses it except devs and webdesigners that'd have installed it previously ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder
{
color: #000 !important;
opacity: 0.5 !important;
}
```

Try this.Opacity value must be in range of 0.1-1.0

Comment: Don't go with !important please